# ClassCastException When Casting NewProxyConnection To C3P0ProxyConnection

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g, c3p0

In our application, we have c3p0 pooled connections configured with hibernate. To call a stored procedure with an input of array type
        I have to get the underlying connection by removing all wrappers. However in this case, I am always getting a ClassCastException when I try to get the C3P0ProxyConnection class.

Is there a simple way to call a stored procedure with complex inputs like arrays?
        In the below code, I have printed some class loader information to see if casting classes are loaded by different class loaders.But it seems all were loaded by the same
        class loader. But the Connection class location is null, so it must be loaded by the Bootstrap class loader. Could this be the issue?

I have attached a snapshot of actual connection object that is coming from the hinernate session factory.

```
private List<InvoicePrintDetailsDTO> getSelectedInvoiceDetailsToPrint(List<Integer> selectedInvoiceIds) {
    Currency defaultCurrency = DAOInstanceFactory.getInstance().getCurrencyDAO().loadCurrencyByCurrencyCode("LKR");
    List<InvoicePrintDetailsDTO> listOfInvoicesToPrint = Collections.emptyList();
    Session session = DAOInstanceFactory.getInstance().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Connection connection = session.connection();

    try {
        Object[] invoiceIds = selectedInvoiceIds.toArray();
        Array invoiceIdsARRAY = getSqlArray(invoiceIds,"SELECTEDINVOICEIDS",connection);

        String query = "{call GETINVOICEPRINTDATA(?,?,?,?)}";
        CallableStatement  ocs = connection.prepareCall(query);
        ocs.setArray(1, invoiceIdsARRAY);
        ocs.setInt(2, defaultCurrency != null ? defaultCurrency.getId() : 0);
        ocs.setInt(3, 1000);
        ocs.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.ARRAY,"INVOICEPRINTINVOICES");
        ocs.executeUpdate();

        Array resultsAsArray = ocs.getArray(8);
        Map<String,Class<?>> resultsAsMap = connection.getTypeMap();
        resultsAsMap.put("INVOICEPRINTINVOICEINFO", Class.forName("com.xxxx.xxxxx.business.utill.InvoicePrintDetailsDTO"));

        if(resultsAsArray!=null) {
            Object[] values = (Object[]) resultsAsArray.getArray();

            if(values != null && values.length > 0) {
                listOfInvoicesToPrint = new ArrayList<InvoicePrintDetailsDTO>();
                for (int i=0; i < values.length; i++){
                    InvoicePrintDetailsDTO obj = (InvoicePrintDetailsDTO)values[i];
                    listOfInvoicesToPrint.add(obj);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        logger.error(ERROR_OCCOURED_WHILE_GENERATING_INVOICE_PRINT, exception);
    } finally {
        try {
            if(connection != null && !connection.isClosed()){
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
            logger.error(ERROR_OCCOURED_WHILE_GENERATING_INVOICE_PRINT, sqlException);
        }
    }
    return listOfInvoicesToPrint;
}

private Array getSqlArray(Object[] data, String sqlTypeName, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    Array array = null;

    Class<? extends Connection> connectionClass = connection.getClass();
    ClassLoader connectionClassLoader = connectionClass.getClassLoader();
    System.out.println("Connection class loader is :"+connectionClassLoader.toString());
    System.out.println("Connection class location :"+connectionClass.getResource('/' + connectionClass.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class"));

    Class<C3P0ProxyConnection> c3P0ProxyConnectionClass = C3P0ProxyConnection.class;
    ClassLoader proxyConnectionLoader = c3P0ProxyConnectionClass.getClassLoader();
    System.out.println("Proxy Connection class loader is :"+proxyConnectionLoader.toString());
    System.out.println("C3P0ProxyConnection class location :"+c3P0ProxyConnectionClass.getResource('/' + c3P0ProxyConnectionClass.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class"));

    Class<NewProxyConnection> newProxyConnectionClass = NewProxyConnection.class;
    ClassLoader newProxyConnectionLoader = newProxyConnectionClass.getClassLoader();
    System.out.println("New Proxy Connection class loader is :"+newProxyConnectionLoader.toString());
    System.out.println("NewProxyConnection class location :"+newProxyConnectionClass.getResource('/' + newProxyConnectionClass.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class"));

    C3P0ProxyConnection proxyValue = (C3P0ProxyConnection) connection;

    if (connection instanceof C3P0ProxyConnection) {
        C3P0ProxyConnection proxy = (C3P0ProxyConnection) connection;
        try {
            Method m = Connection.class.getMethod("createArrayOf", String.class, Object[].class);
            Object[] arrayOfArguments = { sqlTypeName, data };
            array = (Array) proxy.rawConnectionOperation(m, C3P0ProxyConnection.RAW_CONNECTION, arrayOfArguments);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            logger.error("Error calling createArrayOf", exception);
            throw new SQLException(exception);
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

## Error LOG

```
20:36:53,622 INFO  [STDOUT] Connection class loader is :WebappClassLoader
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader@21bdbf51
20:36:53,623 INFO  [STDOUT] Connection class location :null
20:36:53,624 INFO  [STDOUT] Proxy Connection class loader is :WebappClassLoader
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader@21bdbf51
20:36:53,624 INFO  [STDOUT] C3P0ProxyConnection class location :jar:file:/D:/jboss-4.2.2.GA/server/default/deploy/xxxx.war/WEB-INF/lib/c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar!/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/C3P0ProxyConnection.class
20:36:53,625 INFO  [STDOUT] New Proxy Connection class loader is :WebappClassLoader
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader@21bdbf51
20:36:53,626 INFO  [STDOUT] NewProxyConnection class location :jar:file:/D:/jboss-4.2.2.GA/server/default/deploy/xxxx.war/WEB-INF/lib/c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar!/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/impl/NewProxyConnection.class
20:36:53,631 INFO  [STDOUT] ERROR [http-10.10.10.117-8080-6] (InvoicePDFBody.java:316) - Error occoured while generating invoice print.
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy315 cannot be cast to com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0ProxyConnection
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.print.handlers.InvoicePDFBody.getSqlArray(InvoicePDFBody.java:358)
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.print.handlers.InvoicePDFBody.getSelectedInvoiceDetailsToPrint(InvoicePDFBody.java:290)
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.print.handlers.InvoicePDFBody.buildPdfDocument(InvoicePDFBody.java:413)
    at com.xxxx.document.print.controller.InvoicePDFGenerator.buildPdfDocument(InvoicePDFGenerator.java:19)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.document.AbstractPdfView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractPdfView.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.extremecomponents.table.filter.AbstractExportFilter.doFilter(AbstractExportFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.custom.spring.plugin.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.custom.spring.plugin.RoleBasedAccessFilterForInviocePrint.doFilter(RoleBasedAccessFilterForInviocePrint.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.custom.spring.plugin.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a proxy, it probably implements only `Connection` interface

Comment: Do you have any idea to get the implementation from the proxy?
Or any other way to call the stored procedure with complex inputs like Arrays?

Comment: I have no idea why do you try to make a variable with type `C3P0ProxyConnection `

Comment: With c3p0 pooled connections, i feel like it is the only way to call row operation through rawConnectionOperation() method

Comment: You need to unwrap it, how to do that depends on the version you use, but look for how to do that, plenty of answers here.

Comment: hi. what version of c3p0 are you using?

Comment: oh never mind. i see you log the location, in a c3p0-0.9.5.2 jar.

Answer (score 1):

So, a few things:

1. `$Proxy315` is not a `C3P0ProxyConnection`. It is a dynamic proxy generated by hibernate that wraps around a [BorrowedConnectionProxy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/jdbc/BorrowedConnectionProxy.html). Embedded within that might be a `C3P0ProxyConnection`. If you really want to, you can use the static method `BorrowedConnectionProxy.getWrappedConnection(...)` to unwrap to what perhaps is the c3p0 `NewProxyConnection`. You could also use the JDBC Connection standard method [unwrap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Wrapper.html).
2. But you probably don't want to do any of this. Array methods are standard JDBC nowadays, you don't have to unwrap to the native Connection to use them. Just skip all of the fanciness (i.e. skip the c3p0 raw Connection operation stuff), and [call createArrayOf(...) directly on the Connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html).

The only reason why you might have to get the wrapped Connection is if you are using a very old version of hibernate, and the dynamic proxy implements an old version of Connection. If that is the case, then try `BorrowedConnectionProxy.getWrappedConnection(...)` before your cast. And since you are doing a lot of print-debugging, print the Connection you get to make sure it is what you expect.

Comment: Yes. you are correct. Thank you very much. I'll post an answer with the way I did it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes @Steve Waldman you are absolutely correct.
I am getting a Proxy which is not  C3P0ProxyConnection. Therefore there is no easy way, that I can cast it to C3P0ProxyConnection and use c3p0 raw connection operations.
However I have tried to call createArrayOf() directly on the connection I am getting from the hibernate session and failed to do so with same casting exception. 
According to this [Support for JDBC 4.0 Standard](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/jdbcvers.htm#JJDBC28109), I think Oracle does not support the createArrayOf method.
BTY we are using hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar

There is another important thing I have noticed is, when I removed ojdbc6.jar from my application deployment(WEB-INF/lib) and let it load from the JBOSS libs, where I have configured C3P0PooledDataSource,
ClassCastException dissapeared.

## NOTE

I have created Oracle object type to store ids of invoices and change the name of the object type that I have originally created for this input.

## Here is how I finally did it.

```
private ARRAY getSqlArray(List<Integer> listOfInvoiceIds, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
    StructDescriptor selectedInvoiceInfoDescriptior = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("SELECTEDINVOICEINFO", oracleConnection);
    List<STRUCT> listOfInvoices = new ArrayList<STRUCT>();

    for (Object invoiceIdObject : listOfInvoiceIds) {
        listOfInvoices.add(new STRUCT(selectedInvoiceInfoDescriptior,oracleConnection,new Object[] {invoiceIdObject}));
    }
    return new ARRAY(ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("SELECTEDINVOICES",oracleConnection),oracleConnection,listOfInvoices.toArray());
}
```

Steve please feel free to improve this answer or remove it if you feel like it's not accurate.